# Loading files to device in CSS

Tags: css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    html {
        background: url('/img/ground.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        }
    }
```

If I will use smartphone with screen less than 800px, image will downloaded to my device or not?

Comment: It's pretty easy to test. Open developer tools, navigate to stylesheets, add this piece of code. Resize browser. You will see that images gets downloaded only if media query match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used "(min-width: 800px)", so - css-rule will works on screens over 800px width.

Also see documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

probably not because your background URL is invalid.
change it to:
      background: url('../img/ground.png');

Answer (score 0):

The image will not be downloaded by your device browser if the the smartphones width is less then 800px.

You could easily see this by using a program like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and changing your browser width back and forth